# Allow QuadraticCurveTo() to be smoother when filled?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am posting here because i have not found a solution as of yet to fix my situation. I have found a method using antialiasing however that is not good for me since i render on click the translations rewrites and moves the image my 0.5 each time i click.

Anyway to the issue at hand. i have a quadratic curve on my canvas element however when its filled you can see that the shape is not crisp and looks pixelated. Is there a way to improve the smoothness of the shape?

[image]

```js
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("myCanvas");

  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var canvas = c[i];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo( ( 150 - ( 300 / 2 ) ) , 80 );
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , 70, 150 + ( 300 / 2 ), 80);
          ctx.lineTo( 150 + ( 300 / 2 ), 83 );
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , 73, 150 - ( 300 / 2 ), 83);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
  }
```

```html
<canvas class="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<canvas class="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<canvas class="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If your design allows, add a half-pixel stroke to the path:**

[image]

```js
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("myCanvas");

  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    var canvas = c[i];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo( ( 150 - ( 300 / 2 ) ) , 80 );
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , 70, 150 + ( 300 / 2 ), 80);
          ctx.lineTo( 150 + ( 300 / 2 ), 83 );
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , 73, 150 - ( 300 / 2 ), 83);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth=0.50;
        ctx.stroke();
  }
```

```html
<canvas class="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<canvas class="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<canvas class="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```